# Replace NA value with first NonNA value of a column in R

Tags: r, replace, na

I have data frame (df) with multiple column[33] for some column first observation is NA , I want to replace the first row "Na" value with first "Non Na" value. 
if this is my data data frame:

```
x   y  z   zz
1   na na  na
2   na na  na 
3   S  3   na 
4   d  4   7
```

I want my data frame to be

```
x   y  z   zz
1   S  3   7
2   na na  na
3   S  3   na
4   d  4   7
```

I used following code to get the result for a single column but how to dynamically do this for multiple column.

`df$y[1] <- df$y[min(which(!is.na(df$y)))]`

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the logic of your desired output. Why does the second row in `z` have a value of 2? And why does the second row of `y` remain `<NA>`?  Also, do you only want to carry values forward, or can than be carried upward from the last non `<NA>` value?

Comment: sorry , I edited it should remain same .. The second row should remain  same as I just want to change the value of firs row .. if the first row is Na then change it with the first nonNA value.

Comment: `df[1, ] <- lapply(df, function(x) na.omit(x)[1L])`

Comment: Sorry but this did not worked .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to have something like this?

```
df[1,] <- apply(df, 2, function(x) trimws(x[min(which(!is.na(x)))]))
```

**Output is:**

```
  x    y    z   zz
1 1    S    3    7
2 2 <NA> <NA> <NA>
3 3    S    3 <NA>
4 4    d    4    7
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(x = 1:4, y = c(NA, NA, "S", "d"), z = c(NA, NA, 
3L, 4L), zz = c(NA, NA, NA, 7L)), .Names = c("x", "y", "z", "zz"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: GREAT, this is what I was looking . thank you very much

Comment: Glad that it helped!